# i am facing an issue with a script that reads a file and runs sudo su command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

I got this error

```
stty: standard input: Invalid argument
```

When I run a shell script which has the command:

```
sudo su - <name>
```

sample:

```
cat file.txt | while read line
do
echo $line
sudo su - $line
exit
done
```

The file file.txt - contains just user names.

I have admin access, so that's not a problem.

Comment: What are you trying to actually do here? Run a single command under multiple user id's? Or a shell?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing sudo to a user you have to return to the current user by which you are running the script.

Comment: yeah. instead of login into to multiple users and perform a common set of commands. i  tired writing a script.

Answer (score 0):

You can just provide the username to `sudo`:

```
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
...
  -u, --user=user             run command (or edit file) as specified user name or ID
```

Comment: i want to login into each user and then perform a set of operations .